# How to have contours first coordinate always be on the top left?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Ok, so my contours are always rectangles or squares so I have only 4 coordinates for each one ([top_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right]). But for some contours the first coordinate isn't the one on the top_left, it could start from any of 4 corners.
How can I make them always start at one corner every time?

Here are pictures where numbers represent the order of coordinates:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RTt3.png

I use these coordinates to crop the image but if the coordinates are not in the right order it doesn't work.
Here is the code for cropping:

```
def get_colors(img, squares):
    for square in squares:
        x0, y0 = square[0]
        x1, y1 = square[1]
        x2, y2 = square[2]
        x3, y3 = square[3]

        top_left_x = max([x0, x1])
        top_left_y = max([y0, y3])
        bot_right_x = min([x2, x3])
        bot_right_y = min([y1, y2])

        croped = img[top_left_y:bot_right_y, top_left_x:bot_right_x]
```

Comment: See Python OpenCV solution to that problem at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/